# MILLION Collections MeteorJS

Tags: node.js, meteor, database-design, architecture

I have big collection in MeteorJS app, like

```
Animals :{
  name: "some name"
  special: ['foo','bar',...]
  ...
  ...
}
```

Every animal has "special" - some kind of `["4 hands", "2 feet", etc..]`(String array) and there are a lot of this "special" words in it ( more than `600`).

**Problem:** I want to manipulate this("special") words on client (with navigation - searching by special words and so on) and what would be the best way to do this? Create new collection with "special" words and put there `ids` in Posts and feel free to use it on client or do smth else? How best to proceed in this situation?

Comment: You want to store different animals with their names and their special attributes? Please confirm to design database for you

Comment: @ghayel yep, and I wnat to manipulate with all special words on the client

Answer (score 0):

Here is your database design:

[image]

**Explanation:**
There may be many animals in animals table and each animal might have many special words in Special table

Cheers!!

Comment: is my answer helped you?

Comment: I don't understand why I must create new collection if I can put special words in animals DB? It's fater , better or what ? And "special DB"  will looks like this `{id:123,fk1:{animal_id:123,special_words:"a","b","c"}}` ??

Comment: No. Please read my answer word by word. There may be many animals and each animal have many special words this is why I created special table.

Comment: I understand what you did, but I dont understand how it will look, can you show in json format some simple example ?

Comment: `dog :{
  name: "some name"
  special: ['foo','bar',...]
  ...
  ...
}
cat :{
  name: "some name1"
  special: ['foo1','bar1',...]
  name: "some name2"
  special: ['foo2','bar2',...]
  ...
  ...
}` let me know if you still have any question

Comment: Yep, this is first collection I know how it looks, but what about "Special" (or special is not collection??)

Comment: what you mean "special is not collection"?

Comment: Ok, you show me 1st collection called Animals yes? And know I want to see how second collection looks like (Special). And my  "special is not collection", is slight misunderstanding!

Comment: You said in question: `Animals :{
  name: "some name"
  special: ['foo','bar',...]
  ...
  ...
}` that means and animal has name and many specials words. That means you want to store many special words for one animal and there may be many animals so the design is 100% accurate according the your question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98425/discussion-between-ghayel-and-qwe).